# Angular 8 Cannot access 'PaymentOptionsPageModule' before initialization

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to use this npm package hyperid in angular 8 https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyperid.
But I can't import it properly. When I am importing and using it I am getting this error

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PaymentOptionsPageModule' before
> initialization

PaymentOptions is the page name

Here is the code

```
import hyperid from 'hyperid';

ngOnInit() {

    const instance = hyperid()
    const id = instance()
    console.log(id)
    console.log(instance())

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: have your injected `PaymentOptionsPageModule` module in root module ?

Comment: yes. If I remove hyperid import everything works fine

Comment: have you installed the hyperid with save argument.  Ex. npm i hyperid --save

Comment: yes. I have done that

Comment: can you try creating demo on stackblitz ?

Comment: Here is stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7pn4cz

Comment: have you tried 
`import * as hyperid from 'hyperid'` or `import hyperid = require('hyperid')`

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work